# Why is my returned item being undefined if there is no pdo object info PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to asking questions here but my problem is that if there are results to send back my code is fine but if not i get an undefined error with `$info` on the last line.

What i'm trying to do is take my `resultset` and put it into an array `$comments_made` if there are any, if not return `"no comments"`.

If there are results, this code works fine. if not i get an undefined error on the last placement of `$info`.

Maybe i can't see the wood from the trees. i have been looking at it awhile :) Thanks.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
public function retrieveCommentData( $blog__title){

    $query = "select comment from comments where username='$_SESSION[username]' AND blogentrytitle = '$blog__title'";

    $resultSet = $this->db->query($query);

    while($row = $resultSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             //preparing output
             $comments_made[] = $row['comment'];
             $info = $comments_made;
        if(empty($comments_made) || ! $comments_made){
            $info = "No comments.";

        }
        //echo "start"; echo $comments_made; echo "finsih";
    }
    return $info;

    }
```

Comment: You're checking the value of `$comments_made` inside the while loop. You need to move that to after the while loop has finished, instead - otherwise, if there are comments, it'll never be set; if there are no comments, it'll never be reached.

Comment: Actually the first comment there was useful but andy you actually solved it for me thank you, if i could upvote you i would :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no row amount so the `$info` is never set. Your while loop runs through all the rows, if there are no rows, it will never enter the while.

Define the `$info` at the top of your code, before the while

```
public function retrieveCommentData( $blog__title){
   $info = ""
```

Comment: Thanks Henk, my first savior. Rookie move. solved :)